# Mapsforge circle mapview

Tags: android, view, mapsforge

I'm using mapsforge offline maps in my app, I want to show a map like this:

[image]

I tried setting Background of the MapView a circular Shape like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="oval">
  <size
    android:width="120dp"
    android:height="120dp"/>
</shape>
```

but it doesnt work..
Any suggestions?

Comment: You can put your map in to one layout and set drawable for that layout. RelaveLayout will work for that. !

Comment: I tried to put the MapView into a RelativeLayout and se the drawable as backgorund of the relative layout, but it didn't work...